# Is there a story behind the Doom Guy dolls?

Tags: doom-2016

Is there an in-game/in-universe explanation for all the Doom Guy dolls littered about the research base on Mars?

[image: Doom Guy Doll]

There seem to be lots of these things around, are they just arbitrary collectables, or is there some kind of back story as to why this research based has lots of dolls hidden about the place (all modelled after the one thing they didn't necessarily want to wake up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are really just collectibles for going off and checking out all corners of the maps.  The same for the retro Doom levels, they are just a nice secret area to hunt out.

However the DoomWiki does have a small (very small) exert as to their possible inclusion.

> The Doomguy collectible is an approximately nine-inch-tall action figure, evidently created by the UAC to venerate or to celebrate finding the Doom Slayer.

Side bar: As for the research base / scientists not wanting to wake the Doom Slayer, well I think that's more Hell that didn't want to wake him based on the chilling tales within the game of how he nearly brought Hell to it's knees.

[Doomguy Collectible](https://doomwiki.org/wiki/Doomguy_collectible)